# MySQLi prepared statements vs queries

Tags: php, security, mysqli, prepared-statement

It seems like every question on this topic is the difference between mysqli prepared statements and straight mysqli queries in PHP, but nothing on what to do when prepared statements don't meet your needs.

A prepared statement is certainly the way to go when performing a simple query:

```
$stmt = $connection->prepare("SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE id = ?");
```

But what about when things get more complicated? From the PHP manual:

> > However, [markers] are not allowed for identifiers (such as table or column names), in the select list that names the columns to be returned by a SELECT statement, or to specify both operands of a binary operator such as the = equal sign.

This becomes a problem with complicated queries that *do* need to specify both operands of a binary operator, or some of the other restrictions that `mysqli_prepare` has.

In my case, I need to perform some queries to return results for blog entries (This is a simplified example, my connection variable is actually a private property of a blog class, but you get the idea):

```
$query = $connection->query("SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE $field = '$search'");
```

In this example, the `$field` variable is what column to search by, and the `$search` variable is what to search for. This type of query is not possible with prepared statements.

I've done a lot of careful planning for functions such as these, and since I know that there are only X amount of columns to search by, I use conditionals to check that `$field` is equal to one of those columns, and `mysqli_real_escape_string` to escape any possible quote characters. But is this good practice? Based on what I've read and answers here on SO, you should *always* use prepared statements, but I have never seen complicated queries in those examples. Is there a better way to prevent SQL injection, a more advanced way to use prepared statements, or should I just stick to very careful validation here?

Comment: Newcomers picking `mysqli` over `PDO` is usually due to limited research and assumimg by the name similarity that it were the easier migration path. (It is not.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes and no: It is necessary to check the `$field` variable agains a white-list - that is the only way to prevent sql injection - but there is no point in using `mysqli_real_escape_string` on the `$field` variable. If your column name is a reserved word or starts for example with a number, you should quote it in backticks but that is it.

You should still use a prepared statement for the `$search` variable, although here `mysqli_real_escape_string` would also do (instead of a prepared statement, not both).

Comment: Cool, how could I use a prepared statement for just the `$search` variable? Would I have to put the query in a string variable, and then pass that string into the `prepare` method?

Comment: @samrap Yes, you inject the `$field` variable directly but you replace the `$search` variable with a question mark and prepare that string.

Comment: ...or a column contains a space ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Regarding:

```
$query = $connection->query("SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE $field = '$search'");
```

> This type of query is not possible with prepared statements.

It **is** possible to achieve this using prepared statements. As long as the input doesn't come from the client, it is (somewhat) safe to use concatenation on strings when you perform a query, for example:

```
'SELECT * FROM `my_table` WHERE `'.$field.'` = ?'
```

Note that I've included the `?` marker for my prepared statement, and it won't break my query as long as `$field` is a valid column name.

However, **it's a bad practice to do so**, instead you should implement a `switch` or an `if … else` block if you want to perform your query on different column or table names. Example:

```
switch($columnId) {
    case 0:
        $q = 'SELECT * FROM `my_table` WHERE `column0` = ?';
        break;
    case 1:
        $q = 'SELECT * FROM `my_table` WHERE `column1` = ?';
    …
}
```

**Update**:

Or use a whitelist with your column names, as **hakre** suggests:

```
$columns = ['column0', 'column1', 'column2'];
$columnId = $_GET['column'];

if ( isset($columns[$columnId]) ) $field = $columnId;
else throw new Exception('Column not defined');

$q = 'SELECT * FROM `my_table` WHERE `'.$columns[$columnId].'` = ?';
```

Or

```
if ( isset($columns[$columnId]) ) $field = $columns[$columnId];
else throw new Exception('Column not defined');

$q = 'SELECT * FROM `my_table` WHERE `'.$field.'` = ?';
```

In this case I used a numeric index, you can use a key o whatever serves you better.

But if the input comes from the user you should *always* use prepared statements. It's either that or *manually* scape your strings.

Comment: I like the idea of the switch, but I'd rather stick with the cleaner solution provided by @jeroen

Comment: It's the same approach (see the first example) but with sample code; and I just added another way to achieve the same result (2nd example).

Comment: As alternative to a switch you can also create a white-list for column names with an array here. If a column name is used that is not in that array, throw an exception.

Comment: the benefit of a whitelist is using the same instead of the id :) because numbers are harder to remember than names.